# What does the addition of static(...) to the list do?

Tags: django

```
urlpatterns = [path('admin/', admin.site.urls),]
               + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Please explain what is happening here in python. Specifically, how can we add something to the `urlpatterns` list?

Why can't we just make another path within the list and link that to an image instead of using the `static(...)` function?

I'm new to Django and this is confusing me.

Comment: You can if you know them and you remember those routes and can guarantee they will be same - using `static()` saves you effort, required to provide the list elements.

Comment: If you have only handful sure you can add, but usually media files are arbitrary number and grows over time. Also these settings wont work in Production.